# How to convert a Collection to List?

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections, apache-commons-collection

I am using `TreeBidiMap` from the [Apache Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) library. I want to sort this on the values which are `doubles`.

My method is to retrieve a `Collection` of the values using:

```
Collection coll = themap.values();
```

Which naturally works fine.

**Main Question:** I now want to know how I can convert/cast (not sure which is correct) `coll` into a `List` so it can be sorted?

I then intend to iterate over the sorted `List` object, which should be in order and get the appropriate keys from the `TreeBidiMap` (`themap`) using `themap.getKey(iterator.next())` where the iterator will be over the list of `doubles`.

Comment: You might want to avoid this step by directly using some kind of SortedMap, so the entries are in natural order of the keys being used. Java's own TreeMap implements SortedMap.

Comment: `TreeBidiMap` is an `OrderedMap`, the order should be ok. The sorting required in the question is on values, not on keys.

Answer (score 525, accepted):

```
List list = new ArrayList(coll);
Collections.sort(list);
```

As Erel Segal Halevi says below, if coll is already a list, you can skip step one.  But that would depend on the internals of TreeBidiMap.

```
List list;
if (coll instanceof List)
  list = (List)coll;
else
  list = new ArrayList(coll);
```

Comment: Just to note that there are different side effects to the two approaches: casting the collection to a list and then sorting will also sort the original collection; creating a copy will not.

Comment: This approach degrades performance greatly if used repeatedly. See my answer for a solution that works on-the-fly, it involves a custom collection.

Comment: This does not resolve the case when map.values() returns an "inner class" collection. The compiler reports that Collections.sort(List <T>) does not accept Collections.sort(List<InnerClass>).

The solution was even to use:
List<InnerClass> list = map.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList())

Answer (score 114):

Something like this should work, calling the [ArrayList constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-) that takes a Collection:

```
List theList = new ArrayList(coll);
```

Answer (score 35):

I believe you can write it as such:

```
coll.stream().collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Better way to get around casting

Comment: Great! This resolved my case. My map.values() returns an "inner class" collection. The compiler reported that Collections.sort(List <T>) does not accept Collections.sort(List<InnerClass>).

Comment: didn't worked for my use-case in android. requires minimum api 24

Answer (score 34):

I think Paul Tomblin's answer may be wasteful in case coll is already a list, because it will create a new list and copy all elements. If coll contains many elemeents, this may take a long time.

My suggestion is:

```
List list;
if (coll instanceof List)
  list = (List)coll;
else
  list = new ArrayList(coll);
Collections.sort(list);
```

Answer (score 14):

Java 10 introduced `List#copyOf` which returns *unmodifiable List* while preserving the order:

```
List<Integer> list = List.copyOf(coll);
```

Answer (score 10):

```
Collections.sort( new ArrayList( coll ) );
```

Comment: Missing a reference to access ArrayList?

Comment: @Zach: mmhh good point. I knew there was a reason for me to mark this as CW. BTW Paul's ans is the one. I don't know why he has only my uv.

Answer (score 6):

*Java 8 onwards...*

*You can convert Collection to any collection (i.e, List, Set, and Queue) using **Streams** and **Collectors.toCollection()**.*

Consider the following example map

```
Map<Integer, Double> map = Map.of(
    1, 1015.45,
    2, 8956.31,
    3, 1234.86,
    4, 2348.26,
    5, 7351.03
);
```

**to ArrayList**

```
List<Double> arrayList = map.values()
                            .stream()
                            .collect(
                                Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)
                            );
```

> Output: [7351.03, 2348.26, 1234.86, 8956.31, 1015.45]

**to Sorted ArrayList (Ascending order)**

```
List<Double> arrayListSortedAsc = map.values()
                                        .stream()
                                        .sorted()
                                        .collect(
                                            Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)
                                        );
```

> Output: [1015.45, 1234.86, 2348.26, 7351.03, 8956.31]

**to Sorted ArrayList (Descending order)**

```
List<Double> arrayListSortedDesc = map.values()
                                        .stream()
                                        .sorted(
                                            (a, b) -> b.compareTo(a)
                                        )
                                        .collect(
                                            Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)
                                        );
```

> Output: [8956.31, 7351.03, 2348.26, 1234.86, 1015.45]

**to LinkedList**

```
List<Double> linkedList = map.values()
                                .stream()
                                .collect(
                                    Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new)
                                );
```

> Output: [7351.03, 2348.26, 1234.86, 8956.31, 1015.45]

**to HashSet**

```java
Set<Double> hashSet = map.values()
                            .stream()
                            .collect(
                                Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new)
                            );
```

> Output: [2348.26, 8956.31, 1015.45, 1234.86, 7351.03]

**to PriorityQueue**

```
PriorityQueue<Double> priorityQueue = map.values()
                                            .stream()
                                            .collect(
                                                Collectors.toCollection(PriorityQueue::new)
                                            );
```

> Output: [1015.45, 1234.86, 2348.26, 8956.31, 7351.03]

*Reference*

[Java - Package java.util.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

[Java - Package java.util](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 4):

@Kunigami: I think you may be mistaken about Guava's `newArrayList` method.  It does not check whether the Iterable is a List type and simply return the given List as-is.  It *always* creates a new list:

```
@GwtCompatible(serializable = true)
public static <E> ArrayList<E> newArrayList(Iterable<? extends E> elements) {
  checkNotNull(elements); // for GWT
  // Let ArrayList's sizing logic work, if possible
  return (elements instanceof Collection)
      ? new ArrayList<E>(Collections2.cast(elements))
      : newArrayList(elements.iterator());
}
```

Comment: How is this not up-voted more? Kunigami's answer is incorrect (as far as it assumes about the underlying implementation).

Answer (score 1):

What you request is quite a costy operation, make sure you don't need to do it often (e.g in a cycle).

If you need it to stay sorted and you update it frequently, you can create a custom collection. For example, I came up with one that has your `TreeBidiMap` and `TreeMultiset` under the hood. Implement only what you need and care about data integrity.

```
class MyCustomCollection implements Map<K, V> {
    TreeBidiMap<K, V> map;
    TreeMultiset<V> multiset;
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        removeValue(map.put(key, value));
        multiset.add(value);
    }
    public boolean remove(K key) {
        removeValue(map.remove(key));
    }
    /** removes value that was removed/replaced in map */
    private removeValue(V value) {
        if (value != null) {
            multiset.remove(value);
        }
    }
    public Set<K> keySet() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(map.keySet());
    }
    public Collection<V> values() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(multiset);
    }
    // many more methods to be implemented, e.g. count, isEmpty etc.
    // but these are fairly simple
}
```

This way, you have a **sorted** `Multiset` returned from `values()`. However, if you need it to be a list (e.g. you need the array-like `get(index)` method), you'd need something more complex.

For brevity, I only return unmodifiable collections. What @Lino mentioned is correct, and modifying the `keySet` or `values` collection as it is would make it inconsistent. I don't know any consistent way to make the `values` mutable, but the `keySet` could support `remove` if it uses the `remove` method from the `MyCustomCollection` class above.

Comment: `keySet()` and `values()` are Views to the original `Map`, so when they are modified the backing `Map` needs to be modified too, your solution does not support this

Comment: Yeah, you're right about that. To do it right, I'd need to create at least two more collection classes to ensure both keySet and values are backed by both collections. I update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use streams:

```
someCollection.stream().collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score -5):

Here is a sub-optimal solution as a one-liner:

```
Collections.list(Collections.enumeration(coll));
```