# Java: collection that cannot be converted to List

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

In the following code I get an error saying that collection cannot be converted to List. Why not? I thought when the method saveObject is called the part

```
List e = c;
```

equals

```
List e = ArrayList();
```

because c - although of type Collection - refers to ArrayList in the end

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
class Test {
int i;
Object prevObject;
public void saveObject(List e) {
    prevObject = e;
    i++;
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Test t = new Test();
    Collection c = new ArrayList();
    t.saveObject(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Think you should check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580160/how-convert-a-collection-to-list-in-java

Comment: the referenced  duplicate has really no relation with the encountered problem that is related to rules of the compiler to bind a call to a method.

Comment: Disagree that it's a dupe of that question. IMO the question is really more about the compiler and type system. @duke, the problem is that when you declare `Collection c`, you told the compiler to only care about `c` as a `Collection`; thus it essentially ignores the fact that in this particular line, `c` is an `ArrayList`.

Comment: A List is/extends a Collection and not the other way around.

So when you try to pass a Collection to a method which requires a list the collection could be something else (for example a map, set or queue).

Answer (score 3):

Parameter binding happens at compile time, not runtime.  You are trying to pass a `Collection` (which could be anything implementing `Collection`) to a method that is expecting a `List` subclass.  There are `Collection` classes that do not implement `List` so the compiler cannot guarantee that the cast is possible at runtime.

Comment: Specifically, `Set` is a `Collection`.