# How to shuffle a Collection?

Tags: java, collections, shuffle

I know about `Collections.shuffle()`, however it requires a `List`. I'd like to shuffle a `Collection` instead.

```
Collection<Town> towns = getAllTowns();
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: A `Collection` does not necessarily have an order. e.g. _hash sets_ are collections, but has not order. If it's a collection that has no order, it does not make sense to "shuffle" it, does it?

Comment: Note, it's `Collections.shuffle()` not `Collection.shuffle()`, and as you already noted, it can be applied ONLY to something with an intrinsic ordering.  In Java, the base for an ordered collection is `List<>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really possible - the Collection abstraction does not define an order, for example a set is Collection, and ordering is not defined on sets, thus shuffling them doesn't make sense.

You should convert your Collection to a list (if it is not a list already) and then shuffle it. See also: [How to convert a Collection to List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580160/how-to-convert-a-collection-to-list)

Answer (score 2):

`Collection`s can't necessarily be reordered, for example a `Set`. Therefore, you cannot shuffle an arbitrary `Collection`.